# Make ffmpeg read m3u8 from a specified chunk instead of beginning

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a m3u8 contains many chunks of video, how can I make ffmpeg read from, for example, the 13th element in the playlist instead of beginning? (Not by time like EXT-X-START)

I tried #EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:12, but ffmpeg still starts from the first one

Comment: If your modifying the manifest, why not just remove the first 11 chunks?

Comment: I tried removed them, but the chunks are aes encrypted. It seems the #EXT-X-KEY: works with the first chunk?

Comment: No. Every file is encrypted independently.

Comment: Thanks, that works, all I need to do is to add ",IV=0x00000000000000000000000000000000" after EXT-X-KEY